# Trouble with css top on javascript created html object

Tags: css, positioning

I am creating a span in javascript to append to a td.  Works great.  However, for some reason when I call

```
document.getElementById("myTd").appendChild(thisNewSpanObject);
```

the new span seems to think it is a child of the window.  So when I set the attribute of

```
top:-10px;
```

the span is actually off the page, yet aligned horizontally with where it should be, when in reality, I just want it to display 10 pixels above where it would load if it did not have the css property assigned to it.  Should I be using something other than top here?  If I don't use top then the span loads right in place, 10 pixels too low (position:absolute; is set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the `span` element.

You are currently using `position: absolute`, meaning it will be relative to its nearest ancestor with something besides `position: static` (the default for elements) or the document.

Comment: I had not recompiled correctly.  This was the problem, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to the element with ID `myTd`, not the `span`.